# How to find value of innerattributes in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB.And I want to get all values of time in the json like:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"}, "LoginRequest" : { "Time" : "11-06-2012 11:59:33", "innerAttr4" : "innerValue4"} }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113cb"}, "LoginRequest" : { "Time" : "11-06-2012 12:34:05", "innerAttr4" : "innerValue4"} }
```

After searching i found to use the dot notation. But the dot notation is not working for me in java. Can someone tell me how to do this?

I used the dot notation in this manner. But it returns null.

```
        String selectedCollection = "user01"; //WILL CONTAIN THE SELECTED USERNAME
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(selectedCollection);

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        //DBObject obj = coll.findOne("LoginRequest.Time");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
        field.put("LoginRequest.Time", 1);
        DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,field);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
            result.add(obj.getString("LoginRequest.Time"));
            System.out.println(obj.getString("LoginRequest.Time") );
        }
```

It works fine if i am replacing LoginRequest.Time with LoginRequest everywhere. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(BasicDBObject(obj.get("LoginRequest"))).getString("Time")
```